# Access/Excel: Method End of object Range failed?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have an Access db that processes and imports Excel workbooks. It has historically worked well, but is suddenly giving me this error on all workbooks - even ones that previously worked:

```
-2147417851: Method 'End' of object 'Range' failed
```

The line causing the problem is:

```
iLastCBRow = XlBook.Worksheets("4_CensusBlocks").Range("B16001").End(xlUp).Row
```

If I step through this line in the Immediate window and enter

```
XlBook.Worksheets("4_CensusBlocks").Range("B16001").Value
```

it returns the value of that cell correctly.

I thought that the Access db might be corrupt, so I recreated it. Same problem. I also manually forced a repair on the Excel workbook. I even uninstalled and reinstalled Office.

Running Office 2016 64 bit now on Windows 7.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? Thanks

Comment: Try `iLastCBRow = XlBook.Worksheets("4_CensusBlocks").Range("B16001").End(-4162).Row`

Comment: Shot In the Dark: I believe that you are using LateBinding to connect to Excel from Access. `xlUP` is an Excel Constant and hence Access is not able to recognise it.

Comment: Thanks - it does know xlUp because I'm including the Excel object reference. Entering ?xlUp in the immediate window returns -4162. And this code has been working fine for months. I have no idea what might have changed.

Comment: Can you run that line from Excel?

Comment: I dont see anything else wrong with the code.

Comment: Is B16001 the end of your data? or a blank cell below the end of your data? try with B50000 for instance

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, it does work from Excel, and Yes, row 16001 is an "END OF DATA" line. Edit: I uninstalled x64 Office and installed 32 bit. Now I just get Automation Error on that same line.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is because you have more than 16001 lines in the file. The first command

```
iLastCBRow = XlBook.Worksheets("4_CensusBlocks").Range("B16001").End(xlUp).Row)
```

sets iLastCBRow to the starting row.

Try using

```
iLastCBRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
```

instead

Comment: There are actually no more than 16000 rows. The sheet is a data entry sheet where people can enter a list of census blocks; row 16001 is an "END OF DATA" line below which nothing can be entered. I'm just trying to find the last row they entered data in by starting at the END OF DATA and going up. UsedRange won't help because Excel considers everything down to 16001 used (even though there isn't data entered in all of it).

Comment: Yes but i am assuming that for your command to work properly ... it requires at least one blank space between line 16001 and the last line of data. If your data goes up to line 16000 rows then the .End(xlUp) will take it all the way back to the beginning.

Comment: Also ... because I now know that line 16001 is "End of DATA" then the iLastCBRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row command will not work for you unless you delete line 16001

Comment: Thanks Mike. It has to be something in my PC's environment, because an old version of the Access db that always worked fine is giving the same error on old Excel sheets that previously processed just fine.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help Dave ... I would need to see more of your code to figure out the problem. Your code above looks good if the data doesn't exceed 15999 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand WHY, but the problem seems to have been in using early binding of Excel object variables. Once I put in place

```
dim xl as object 
dim xlbook as object
set xl = createobject("Excel.Application")
set xlbook = xl.workbooks.open(filename)
```

Instead of just

```
dim xlbook as excel.workbook
set xlbook = getobject(filename)
```

The error went away. I have only had Office 2016 installed this whole time, so perhaps an update made the OLE server think that I had multiple Offices installed or something?? No idea.